# Need help with sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table of emails. And i need that Each user received email.

SO i made:

```
script/generate mailer Notifier
```

Next.

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  def newgrants_notification(respondent)
     recipients user.email
     from       "lala@lala.com"
     subject    "Hi!"
     body       (:respondent => respondent)
  end
end
```

In `app/views/notifier/newgrants_notification.erb`
wrote : `Hello!`

and this my controller where i create question

```
@question = Question.create(:text => params[:question][:text], :security => rand(888).to_i)

if success = @question.save
  respondents = Respondent.find(:all)
  respondents.each do |res|
    Inquiry.create(:question_id=>@question.id.to_i, :respondent_id=>res.id.to_i)
    Notifier.newgrants_notification(respondents).deliver #this is right??
  end
```

what mistakes i did? messages aren't coming ;(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HI

```
respondents.each do |res|
  Inquiry.create(:question_id=>@question.id.to_i, :respondent_id=>res.id.to_i)
  Notifier.newgrants_notification(res).deliver
end
```

When you are sending mail,the mail id is passed as a parameter so respondents is replaced with res.

Comment: Thank you, now i understand, and i receive emails only when project will be in production mode?

Comment: recipients user.email also check this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485348/how-does-actionmailer-work/5485972#5485972

Answer (score 1):

You are passing through your array of respondents, when you use each, the variable in the pipes (|res|) is the one to use to refer to the singular object in the loop.

```
Notifier.newgrants_notification(res).deliver
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed this part!

Answer (score 1):

In development mode all email are not send. It's all log only in your log file. So if you test on this environment is normal. Check on your log if you see it :)

Comment: Oh yes, i see this:) Thank you, and in log i see: "Sent mail to user@lala.com" , so all is working perfectly?

Comment: It's work fine. Now you need test with your email configuration to be sure. it's works. But check you sendmail or your smtp to see if it's not him they are some error.

Comment: Nice. I din't write anywhere smtp ;o Is it bad? If yes, where i should write? Now works fine, if i have 5 emails in database, in log i receive 5 emails. Good!